# How to calculate stream order in GRASS 7.0.2?

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology, watershed

I would like to calculate Strahler's and other stream hierarchy from my input raster but I am not sure how.
[This manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.stream.order.html) suggests tat I should use `r.stream.order` command, however in version 7.0.2 "order" is not a recognized command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you are accessing GRASS, but the documentation reads to me like this is an Addon. I just went to the command line typed "g.extension" and a window popped up that I linked to the source page (https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/raster/) and put in the addon name (r.stream.order)... and it did its thing... hopefully that does it for you :)

Comment: I was going to suggest the same.

Comment: Thanks. I came to this conclusion. Marking as answered because it answers this question.  Now I have a new issue; the addon wil not install and raises an error: "ERROR: File is not a zip file: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/addons/grass-7.0.2/r.stream.order.zip"  Any ideas?

Comment: This happened to me when I first tried. I changed the path on the "Optional" tab from "http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7" to the path above (with /raster/ at the end)... but now I can't replicate the failure message. It seems to just be a web link, but I am not sure how it is a zip file. In theory you should be able to dump this into the command line:

Comment: g.extension extension=r.stream.order operation=add svnurl=https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/raster/

Comment: Turns out i was running 7.0.2. After installing 7.0.4 i was able to install and run the addons. Of course now my extracted streams (which should run the same or similar algorithm as r.watershed) do not exactly match the stream output from  r.watershed but that's another topic.